# Scrolling items on screen [iOS cocos2d]

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

OK so in my game I need the users to scroll between items, just like you scroll a web page in Safari. Is there any way to do that? If not, maybe scrolling them to the side, like you do in the spriboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure I have understood what you would like to do, but there is a cocos2d extension that seems appropriate to it: [CCScrollLayer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1506#more-1506).

> CCLayer subclass that lets you pass-in an array of layers and it will then create a smooth scroller. Complete with the “snapping” effect.

If you are looking for a generic scrolling within your view, I suggest [this tutorial](http://johnehartzog.com/2009/10/2d-scrolling-game-with-cocos2d-tilemap-with-zoom/) or this topic rom [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5363) list.

EDIT:

I have never done it, but I think it should be possible to scale the `CCScrollLayer` to the size you need.

Otherwise, you might change the contentSize of the layer, or even put the `CCScrollLayer` into a clipping node.

Anyway, I think that it is much easier to start from this and find a way to adapt it to your specific requirements than start from scratch.

Comment: Hey, I already found this CCScrollLayer, but is there a way to do that not on all the screen? I need this only in a 200px space area.